# How to remove the image element from DOM when 403 error occurs in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

Is there a way I can remove the entire image element from DOM when 403 error occurs to that image while fetching it from the API so that the `title` of the card is expanded to the whole width of the card.

[image: card with no image]

This is what I tried so far

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <div>{{ item.title }}</div>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="4" class="ion-text-center">
      <img src="{{ item.imageurl }}" (error)="handleImageError($event)" />
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
  handleImageError(e) {
    e.target.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

I have created a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-zdnvwt?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html) using StackBlitz. Could anyone please help.

Comment: Can u share html code of container which includes  img tag ?

Comment: @pc_coder I just updated my question

Comment: U need to use ngIf  for your ion-col tag that includes image. Than show hide due to its loading

Comment: @pc_coder Created a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-zdnvwt?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html) here using Stackblitz

Comment: I edited answer and put link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-a5wy8u

Comment: @Pavan check my answer. That should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for ***ngIf** on image container, as it removes / adds the element from the DOM. And you will also have to slightly modify the `handleImageError`.

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8tdjpf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <div>{{ item.title }}</div>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col *ngIf="!item.hide" size="4" class="ion-text-center">
      <img [src]="item.imageurl" (error)="handleImageError(item)" />
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</div>
```

And then in the script, in the `handleImageError` - do this:

```
items = [
  {imageUrl: '5353ssa.png'},
  {imageUrl: 'https://latam.kaspersky.com/content/es-mx/images/product-icon-KSOS.png'},
  {imageUrl: '5353ssa.png'},
  {imageUrl: '5353ssa.png'},
]

handleImageError(image) {
  image.hide = true;
}
```

Comment: The `*ngIf` should be on the container, else the space will still be reserved (in OP's case).

Comment: @Pavan I've modified the answer to match your edited question.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is about your container. U have two columns. Then u will hide column instead of image. U can use ngIf
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-a5wy8u

```
<ion-col *ngIf="!car.isSHOW">
    <ion-card-content>
        <img src="{{car.url}}" (error)="handleImageError(car)">
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-col>
```

in component change its to true

```
handleImageError(e) {
   e.isSHOW = true;
  }
```

Comment: Tried this way but It removes the image from all the items in the array.

Comment: U put ishow attribute to foreach model as default true.

Comment: There is no need to include a boolean, you can just write `*ngIf="item.imageUrl"`

Comment: Yes right @Mike S. but he has url . Problem is that if it is valid or not. then I put one more attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use ngIf to hide the complete image, the way I would have address this is

1. Create a boolean variable at the top of your component.

   let shouldHide = false;
2. Use this variable and ngIf at your image, you can use this at the container level or the image level itself like.

   ```
    <img src="{{ imageurl }}" (error)="handleImageError($event)"  *ngIf="shoudHide"/>
   ```

   3. Assign true in case of error

      handleImageError(e) {
      e.target.style.display = 'none';
      this.shouldHide = true;
      }

Hope it helps